# How does OpenGL convert single component textures?

Tags: opengl

I am confused as to how OpenGL stores single component textures(like GL_RED).

> The GL converts it to floating point and assembles it into an RGBA element by attaching 0 for green and blue, and 1 for alpha.

Does this mean that my texture will take 32 bpp in graphic memory even though I only give 8 bpp?

Also I would like to know how OpenGL converts bytes to float for operations in the shader. It doesn't seem logical to simply divide by 255..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't know, and you have no way of knowing (ok ok, I kind of lied... there exists [documentation](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/opengl/texture_formats/nv_ogl_texture_formats.pdf) which tells you those details for some particular hardware. But *in general* you have no way of knowing, because you don't know in advance what hardware your program will run on).

OpenGL stores textures *somewhat* following your request, but it finally chooses something that the hardware supports. If that means that it converts your input data to something completely different, it does that silently.

For example, most implementations convert RGB to RGBA because that's more convenient for memory accesses. The same goes for 5-5-5 data being converted to 8-8-8 and similar.

Usually, a 8 bpp texture will take only 1 byte per pixel nowadays (since pretty much every card supports that, and for software implementations it does not matter), though this is not something you can 100% rely on. You should not worry either, though... it will make sure that it somehow works.

Similar can happen with non-power-of-two textures too, by the way. On all modern versions of OpenGL, this is supported (beginning with 2.0 if I remember right). Though, at least in theory, some older cards might not support this feature.
In that case, OpenGL would just silently make the texture the next bigger power-of-two size and only use a part of it (without telling you!).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know how OpenGL converts 8bit color values to float for when you use them in the shader?

Comment: Conceptually, simply by dividing by 255... but I don't know whether there is _actually_ a division going on or a lookup table. Seeing how a 256-entry lookup table is trivially cheap and division is expensive, I would assume lookup tables. Gamma correction usually works with lookup tables too, rather than really using `pow`.

Comment: Ok thanks! I was thinking it might be by adding one and dividing by 256 because dividing by 255 = precision loss.

Comment: Adding one would be imprecise too, though. The math is relatively simple: `0/255 = 0.0` and `255/255 = 1.0`.

Comment: Actually it is not that simple, see http://kaba.hilvi.org/programming/range/index.htm

Comment: _"This paper discusses the scalar quantization of a real number range [-1, 1] to a p-bit signed integer range"_  -- That is a different thing. Different interval, and more generalized. But yes, for a general solution with arbitrary bit length in an interval that is not bounded by zero, things do get more complicated.